# Uno platform setup

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, uno-platform

I'm trying to set up a desktop application using Uno Platform. I have been trying that for a week and it's not working. In the period of downloading the platform my incternet connection wasn't that great so I doubt it's like packeges have not been downloaded correctly but I can't find a way to solve my problem. I have tried use the Uno Platform template wizard to build it. the command was:

```
dotnet new unoapp -o unot2 -preset "recommended" -id "com.companyname.unot2" -pub "O=unot2" -platforms "maccatalyst" -platforms "windows" -theme-service  -vscode  -pwa False -theme "material" -presentation "mvux" -config  -di  -log "default" -nav "regions" -http  -loc  -server  -tests "unit" -tests "ui" -toolkit  -dsp
```

I got that huge failure list:

```
The template "Uno Platform App" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj : warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj : warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj : warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'FluentAssertions (>= 6.12.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (>= 17.8.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit (>= 4.0.1)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit3TestAdapter (>= 4.5.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'coverlet.collector (>= 6.0.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Server\unot2.Server.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 6.5.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'FluentAssertions (>= 6.12.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (>= 17.8.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Newtonsoft.Json (>= 13.0.3)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit (>= 4.0.1)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit3TestAdapter (>= 4.5.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Uno.UITest.Helpers (>= 1.1.0-dev.70)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.UITest (>= 4.3.3)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source. [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.sln]
  Restored C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.DataContracts\unot2.DataContracts.csproj (in 332 ms).
  Failed to restore C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj (in 329 ms).
  Failed to restore C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj (in 333 ms).
  Failed to restore C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Server\unot2.Server.csproj (in 387 ms).
Restore failed.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj : error : Could not resolve SDK "Uno.Sdk". Exactly one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj : error :   SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" returned null.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj : error :   Unable to resolve 'Uno.Sdk (= 5.1.50)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v0.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj : error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "Uno.Sdk" because directory "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Sdks\Uno.Sdk\Sdk" did not exist.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2\unot2.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Uno.Sdk' specified could not be found.
Restore failed.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Shared\unot2.Shared.csproj:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Shared\unot2.Shared.csproj : error : Could not resolve SDK "Microsoft.Build.NoTargets". Exactly one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Shared\unot2.Shared.csproj : error :   SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" returned null.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Shared\unot2.Shared.csproj : error :   Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Build.NoTargets (= 3.7.56)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v0.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Shared\unot2.Shared.csproj : error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" because directory "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Sdks\Microsoft.Build.NoTargets\Sdk" did not exist.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Shared\unot2.Shared.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.Build.NoTargets' specified could not be found.
Restore failed.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Server\unot2.Server.csproj:
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Server\unot2.Server.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 6.5.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
  Failed to restore C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Server\unot2.Server.csproj (in 67 ms).
  1 of 2 projects are up-to-date for restore.
Restore failed.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.DataContracts\unot2.DataContracts.csproj:
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
Restore succeeded.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj:
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'FluentAssertions (>= 6.12.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (>= 17.8.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit (>= 4.0.1)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit3TestAdapter (>= 4.5.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'coverlet.collector (>= 6.0.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
  Failed to restore C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Tests\unot2.Tests.csproj (in 18 ms).
Restore failed.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj:
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'FluentAssertions (>= 6.12.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (>= 17.8.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Newtonsoft.Json (>= 13.0.3)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit (>= 4.0.1)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NUnit3TestAdapter (>= 4.5.0)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Uno.UITest.Helpers (>= 1.1.0-dev.70)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.UITest (>= 4.3.3)' for 'net8.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
  Failed to restore C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.UITests\unot2.UITests.csproj (in 13 ms).
Restore failed.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\Directory.Packages.props:
Restore succeeded.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj : error : Could not resolve SDK "Uno.Sdk". Exactly one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj : error :   SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" returned null.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj : error :   Unable to resolve 'Uno.Sdk (= 5.1.50)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v0.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj : error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "Uno.Sdk" because directory "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Sdks\Uno.Sdk\Sdk" did not exist.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Mobile\unot2.Mobile.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Uno.Sdk' specified could not be found.
Restore failed.
Restoring C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj : error : Could not resolve SDK "Uno.Sdk". Exactly one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj : error :   SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" returned null.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj : error :   Unable to resolve 'Uno.Sdk (= 5.1.50)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v0.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: contoso.com, NuGet official package source.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj : error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "Uno.Sdk" because directory "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Sdks\Uno.Sdk\Sdk" did not exist.
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\uno platform\t4\unot2\unot2.Windows\unot2.Windows.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Uno.Sdk' specified could not be found.
Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
```

In addition, I noticed that:
`Skipping NuGet package signature verification.`

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded my uno environment to .NET 8 and tried to check, if there's an issue with .NET 8 SDK or the FluentAssertions NuGet package, but could not reproduce your problem. Therefore I would guess, it might be related to your local installation.

Try to update it to the latest version and check the installation subsquently using the commands:

`dotnet tool update -g uno.check`

`uno-check`

There should be no warnings or errors. FluentAssertions seems to had an issue when .NET 8 came out, but your post seems newer (https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/2465). Maybe you can just check and update your post with the uno-check information, if the update/check don't resolve the problem.